# Массив координат в JSON объекте

Tags: json, парсер, java

Есть JSON объект, в котором есть массив координат вида [x,y]. Как можно распарсить этот объект, чтобы использовать далее X и Y отдельно. 
У меня есть вариант такой: преобразовывать этот объект в строку и писать в X начиная со второго символа и до запятой, а в Y после запятой и до предпоследнего символа. Но это всё очень неуклюжо и коряво.

Comment: ДОМ парсер нид хелп ю =)

Answer (score 2):

Как насчет чего-нибудь из этого списка:

- [JSON](http://www.json.org/java/)
- [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
- [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)
- [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

Comment: я пользуюсь json - simple. Но вопрос же не в этом) Простите, может не совсем правильно описал проблему. Объект я получаю, проблем с этим нет. Внутри объекта, есть массив из координат. Поэтому когда я получаю объект, я сначала передаю его JSONArray и оттуда уже "дёргаю" с помощью get(). По сути это получается ArrayList объектов вида [x,y]. Вопрос как эти значения нормально "вытащить" из этого объекта. Должен же быть адекватный способ без изобретения велосипеда. Просто я не знаю как это сделать правильно. Фуф, много по написал)

Comment: В общем такой у меня велосипед получился

    class Pair {
     int x = 0;
     int y = 0;
     
     public void setPair(Object obj) {
      String str = obj.toString();
      int z, s;
      z = str.indexOf(",");
      s = str.indexOf("]");
      x = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1, z));
      y = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(++z, s));
     }
    }

Comment: Почему вы не распарсите теми же средствами массив  `[x,y]` ?